# Allow duplicate matches for a CASE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

How could I show all values of MatchID that match in this WHERE CASE statement:

```
SELECT 
   `Word`, 
   CASE
       WHEN `Word` LIKE 'a%' THEN 12
       WHEN `Word` LIKE 'b%' THEN 13 
       WHEN `Word` LIKE 'a%' THEN 14
       ELSE -1 
    END AS MatchID
FROM `Words`
```

My table contains a, b, and c, let's say.  Right now, the results of this table are only showing:

```
a   12
b   13
```

I want it to also show:

```
a   14
```

In other words, I want the CASE clause to show all matches, not just the first match.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This means you want the a row to generate 2 rows: that doesn't make sense. CASE is evaluated *once* per row and short circuits too: you have one "a" row so you get 12. One row cannot make 2 rows for a single SELECT. A UNION will add a lot of overhead as you commented. So, what is the actual problem you want to solve...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant way to do what you're asking, but here's one possible solution:

```
SELECT `Word`, 12 AS MatchID FROM `Words` WHERE `Word` like 'a%'
UNION
SELECT `Word`, 13 AS MatchID FROM `Words` WHERE `Word` like 'b%'
UNION
SELECT `Word`, 14 AS MatchID FROM `Words` WHERE `Word` like 'a%'
```

**EDIT**: If performance is a large concern then you could also consider a hybrid approach; use one SELECT with a CASE statement for *a%* and *b%*, and then UNION that with another SELECT for the second *a%*.

Comment: With your method, MySQL would need to filter through the table three times, right?  Do you think that's much slower than having it filter through once and check each word three times, as I was doing?

Comment: @Carl, your sample data is meaningless for us but I have the impression that you should reconsider the complete query. With the specs you wrote, this is the basically the only way.

Comment: Going through the table three times is definitely slower than going through it once; however, I know of no other way to have a single row be counted multiple times in one query. If your `word` column is properly indexed for searching then the performance impact should be minimal.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should also work.

```
SELECT `Word`,
       COALESCE(`MatchID`, -1) AS `MatchID`
FROM   `Words`
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'a%' AS `Match`, 12   AS `MatchID`
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'b%' AS `Match`, 13   AS `MatchID`
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'a%' AS `Match`, 14   AS `MatchID`) AS `Matches`
         ON `Words`.`Word` LIKE `Matches`.`Match`
```